# Statemachine in RTS game

Tags: state-machine

I am working on an RTS game and I want to be able to build structures, which means that a builder will walk to target location and, once there, start building.
I want to implement a statemachine in every unit where states can be added as the user gives input because this might come in handy later, when units guard position and stuff. 
My question is: is it useful to create a statemachine for every individual, user-owned unit or is this a pitfall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**State machines are common in games.**

A state machine is the usual approach for behavior of objects, NPCs, etc in games.

They are so commonly used that they are often supported by game engines: e.g.: [Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StateMachineBasics.html)

A state machine pitfall might be resource consumption by a naive implementation, e.g. one employing a [State Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern), which is ok only if don't have relatively few state machines running at the same time, otherwise resource consumption of a State Pattern would be prohibitively high for thousand of concurrent state machines.

If you indeed intend to have thousands of individual state machines running at the same time, or need extreme efficiency, you will have to implement them with a simpler approaches: eg: nested switch statements or table based implementations [examples in C](http://johnsantic.com/comp/state.html).

**Reasons for using State Machines, in general, not only in games.**

The main reason for using state machines is modeling your problem with clarity: You can think about edge conditions visually, by drawing out the state machine, e.g. by using tools such as GraphViz or by hand.
It easier to see what would happen in which scenario, precisely.

Sometimes your problem "just calls" for a State Machine representation: it has "states", and complex behaviors, which depend on past events.

State machines have decades of computer science research behind them,  and algorithms about analyzing them, simplifying them, etc are known.

If you try to model a state machine "by adding and removing IF statements", by hand, [you will end up with messier code](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html), which you won't be able to transform, model, etc.

On the "cons" side, if you use table based state machines, debugging them would be somewhat hard.

Comment: Thank you for the thourough explanation :)